# Examples of when the professional scientists or mathematicians were wrong, but the nonprofessionals were right

Tags: mathematicians, examples, big-list, scientists

What are the most glaring examples — if any — of when the professional scientists or mathematicians were wrong, but the nonprofessionals were right?

Comment: Two things: math was far ahead of nearly all fields of science in its rigor and procedures until relatively recently;  and in nearly all cases "nonprofessionals" were right in a tiny percentage of their beliefs.  They were correct by accident, not by insight.

Comment: I don't know the local standards but isn't this just a list question and hence should be closed?

Comment: I don't recall the details, but wasn't it originally believed that rocket travel in space was impossible because with no atmosphere, there's nothing to push against and therefore, by Newton's Third Law, no way to get acceleration?

Comment: @MasonWheeler: I don't know the history, but I would be really surprised if that was the case. Conservation of momentum is a very basic fact in Newtonian mechanis, so the idea of "I expel matter in one direction, I move in the other" should have been obvious to any physicist.

Comment: @TimB: Yes, I'd say it definitely is. There's no way to choose a "best" answer, as OP's just asking for an unbounded list. ("Most glaring" isn't really a clear, specific criterion.)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft is very right in what he says. Ramanujan would be an excellent example of this, falling short of rigour but still dragging the establishment along with him. The man who knew infinity is an excellent film to watch also. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan

Comment: @MasonWheeler You are undoubtedly thinking of this famous New York Times article, worth reading in its entirety:
https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_New_York_Times/Robert_Goddard
As you can see, it is actually an illustration of the opposite. Goddard, a professional scientist, was quite right about the dynamics of rocketry and how action and reaction actually work, while the amateur writer of the article was wrong.

Comment: It is particularly amusing when he says that only "Dr. Einstein" is "licensed" to change the laws of mechanics.

Comment: If you consider education/instruction a science, then you could look to Siegfried Engelmann as a clear example of a nonprofessional beating out the professionals. "The DOE-approved models were developed by academics in education with the exception of one, the Direct Instruction model, which had been developed by an expert Illinois preschool teacher with no formal training in educational methods." Direct Instruction beat out all other models in the largest educational study every conducted. Here's the [story](https://darkwing.uoregon.edu/~adiep/ft/grossen.htm)

Comment: The amount of votes and answers this question has accumulated in such short time seems quite telling for the state of hsm.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold It's been a regular on the HNQ list, so all it says is that HSM is a relatively quiet site that's easily skewed by a bunch of new users coming across a question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby "relatively quiet" is a nice way of putting it. Hopefully the newly attracted users are relatively experts in the history of science.

Comment: Define "wrong".  Remembering that the scientific method is to essentially reject suggestions until evidence is demonstrates otherwise, are you asking for cases where evidence was slow to be gathered (which I don't believe wrong); or where the evidence for a theory was insufficient and a theory was disproved?

Answer (score 64):

It seems **ball lightning** was disbelieved by scientists until around 1960.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_lightning) .

I knew a geologist who told us how his eye-witness account of ball lightning had been ridiculed.  He had learned not to mention it when he interviewed for jobs as a professor of geology.

Comment: Eyewitnesses are routinely disbelieved because witness reports are the second-least-reliable source of information.

Comment: @Mark what's the least reliable?

Comment: @PedroA, an eyewitness report as relayed by a third party.

Comment: @Mark: I thought that dishonour is reserved for facebook/twitter posts?

Comment: It doesn't help that ball lightning only lasts one turn.

Comment: [Upper atmospheric lightening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper-atmospheric_lightning#History) appears to have a similar story - although predicted well before observed by aircraft pilots, meteorologists dismissed aircraft pilots' observations.

Comment: What can be claimed without evidence can be dismissed without evidence... It's not that the scientists were exactly wrong, but it just took a long time to obtain the evidence.

Comment: Earthquake lights are another example in this category.

Comment: @user21820. No - in fact Stack Exchange comments are the least reliable source of information in the world. 100% fact ;-)

Comment: @UKMonkey there is a difference between "you stupid bum couldn't see such a thing, it's a myth and you are really stupid" and "I have no clear evidence of that so even though you could tell the truth I will continue considering it doesn't exist until I can get some hard proof". Unfortunately most would be scientists are from the first flock.

Answer (score 56):

In 1726's *[Gulliver's Travels](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1402743394)*, Jonathan Swift mocked the learned scientists of Britain for not having solved the [Longitude](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/080271529X) problem:  Figure out a way to keep track of one's east-west location to within a mile after making a round-trip across the Atlantic.  This was one of the most important scientific challenges of the 18th century.  The British Parliament had an outstanding offer of £ 20,000 for a solution, and had trusted the astronomers at the Royal Observatory with awarding the prize.  The prize was worth several times the modern-day Nobel Prize, and was famous at the time.

In 1731, a watchmaker named [John Harrison](https://www.infogalactic.com/info/John_Harrison) solved the problem.  The astronomers at the Observatory refused to believe him.  Over the next 40 years, Harrison steadily refined his solution, but the astronomers never did award him the prize.  It took an act of Parliament in 1773 before Harrison was finally given his prize, and east-west navigation could be made safe.

Comment: I don't think Harrison counts as a non-professional. His solution was to use an accurate clock, and he was a professional clockmaker.

Comment: The question implies that it considers as "nonprofessionals" all those who aren't "professional scientists or mathematicians". So Harrison would appear to qualify. I am not sure, however, whether professional scientists or mathematicians thought he was wrong, and think the answer would benefit from links to relevant sources that demonstrate that.

Comment: @njuffa -- I linked to a [book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/080271529X)-length source that discusses the ways in which the professional scientists thought he had insufficiently answered the question.

Comment: For the history of the chronometer, it was not that scientists didn't believe that the chronometer could work. Rather, scientists believed that there should be a more "elegant" solution that does not simply rely on measuring time difference to determine longitude similar to how sextants can be used to measure latitude.

Comment: Everyone should read the wonderful book “Longitude”, by Dava Sobel.  See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude_(book)

Comment: @njuffa that seems to be leading to a True Scotsman issue over what constitutes a "professional scientist or mathematician". For example, is a physician who discovers a cure considered a scientist if he has only his "clinical" MD doctorate rather than a "research" PhD? If a professional engineer discovers something new about material science, does that count or is he also a "scientist"? What about clinical psychologists? Public school teachers?

Comment: Are you aware of how much your answer is myth? Or what are the sources for your version?  Just one example of the distance from historical fact: the last sentence in the answer alone ignores that the Nautical Almanac became  available for 1767 onwards and sold in large copy-runs,  facilitating longitude-finding by the lunar method. Harrison's one-off timekeepers showed that usefully accurate chronometers could be made, yes he pointed the way, but until such things were reliably made in quantity at affordable price, which was not until decades after him, they were not yet a solution.

Comment: @RobertColumbia To expand on that, Harrison was arguably an engineer, which should be included in "professionals". There were some scientists who thought we couldn't get to the Moon, and a bunch of engineers, not scientists, built a rocket and we went to the Moon. Repeat argument for any large-scale modern endeavor.

Comment: Why link to a Wikipedia clone site instead of Wikipedia itself?

Comment: "In 1741, hundreds of British sailors died..." Just for completeness, a link there to some source would make the answer even better.

Comment: Also in Gulliver's Travels (1726) the foolish astronomers in a particularly outlandish destination believed that the planet Mars had two small moons, with orbital periods in the region of one or two Earth days. Phobos and Deimos were discovered about 150 years later, with orbital periods of 8 and 30 hours...

Comment: @user253751 InfoGalactic advertises itself as a less "left-wing" and "politically correct" fork of Wikipedia, with "relaxed standards" on notability and original research.

Comment: @costrom In this case the Infogalactic page is just an older version of the Wikipedia page. There are no obvious "anti-left-wing" edits.

Answer (score 38):

This isn't a topic I'm familiar with, just something I've read on Quanta, but according to [this article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/pentagon-tiling-proof-solves-century-old-math-problem-20170711/), Richard Kershner of Johns Hopkins [claimed to have a complete classification of convex pentagon tilings](https://www.jhuapl.edu/techdigest/views/pdfs/V08_N6_1969/V8_N6_1969_Kershner.pdf) in 1968, though he notably said that "The proof that the list in Theorems 1 and 2 is complete is extremely laborious and will be given elsewhere" and that "a complete proof would require a rather large book".

However, after Martin Gardner talked about this claim in his column in *Scientific American* in 1975, it got to Marjorie Rice, a California housewife with a high school math education, who found four additional families, and Richard James, a computer programmer, who found another. Eventually, Michael Rao proved that there were exactly 15. You can read more about Rice in [this article by the same author](https://www.quantamagazine.org/marjorie-rices-secret-pentagons-20170711/).

Admittedly, this is an instance of a single professional mathematician making a false claim without giving a proof, which mathematicians consider poor form, and a nonprofessional correcting him, rather than the general mathematics community being wrong.

Comment: Isn’t there a similar story about Latin squares?

Comment: Thanks for the link to the interesting story about Marjorie Rice. It makes me wonder how much humanity is held back by gender and social inequality. How much talent wasted, how much potential unrealized. A shame even from a purely utilitarian viewpoint. What isn't there is not missed, but it must be a lot.

Answer (score 30):

I think a famous example is the [Monty Hall problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem) about switching doors. The problem was answered correctly by [Marilyn vos Savant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marilyn_vos_Savant), but she got baskets of letters from experts that she is wrong.

Comment: But the rate of correct answers was far higher among the educated (at least in math and physics) than among the great unwashed masses.

Comment: @ Carl Witthoft, do you have hard data about this or is it just a guess?

Comment: This is not an accurate description of what happened. Marilyn Vos Savant thought she was answering the Monty Hall problem but was actually answering the evil Monty problem, which has a different answer. Lots of people wrote to explain to her that she was wrong and she stubbornly insisted that they were wrong. (In her statement of the problem, Monty offers to let you switch doors after he knows which door you chose with no requirement to do so. For all you know, Monty only extends this offer to people who he knows chose the right door. So switching could guarantee a loss in this variant.)

Comment: Also, please note that (1) the problem permeated the mathematics community *far* ahead of vos Savant's rise to prominence; (2) the large majority of professional mathematicians were *right* about the problem.  "baskets of letters" does not necessarily represent "the professional ... mathematicians" as a whole.

Comment: Karl, re Carl Witthoft's comment MvS wrote "Of the letters from the general public, 92% are against my answer, and of the letters from universities, 65% are against my answer." @David Schwartz, it's true that the problem has no solution unless you state Monty's general strategy; neither the asker of the question nor vos Savant did that; and from her explanations it's not clear that she understands how critical Monty's motivation is. However, the authors of the letters she quoted don't seem to understand that either, and no one mentioned evil Monty (or any other well-defined Monty).

Comment: @benrg That's likely because the letters she picked were from people unfamiliar with the problem. She gave them the evil Monty problem and the wrong answer to it and they explained that she was wrong. If they were unfamiliar with the Monty Hall problem, they couldn't have explained that she mis-stated the problem, only that she gave the wrong answer to the problem she did state, which she did. It seems that she didn't understand the problem either and how critical it is that we must know that Monty was required to let us switch.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, the problem can be interpreted in other ways, but this framing of the story is callous and disingenuous. Marilyn Vos Savant was given a riddle which was missing information. She did what any reasonable person would do in that situation, and she reconstructed the *intended* riddle from the context. (might I add that the majority of her critics agree on the intended riddle here) This is made clear in her ending remarks: "Suppose there are a million doors, and you pick door No. 1. Then the host, who knows what's behind the doors and will always avoid the one with the prize."

Comment: @Ryan Why do you say she was given a riddle that was missing information? Since she clearly understood it only one way, she must at least have figured out the missing information. Why would she then pass on a mis-statement of the problem that's missing critical information? Those ending remarks are, at best, ambiguous -- further evidence she didn't realize how critical this point was. Numerous people wrote to her to correct her error, and she stubbornly insisted that she was write all along. She was not.

Comment: This was a fun incident because, although I'm sure it's true that the majority of mathematicians got it right, the ones that got it wrong and made complete fools of themselves in doing so was very entertaining.   See http://www.stayorswitch.com/history.html .  I particularly like the quote from Everett Harman, Ph.D.

Comment: @DonHatch - The sexist ones are particularly atrocious - one would hope professional mathematicians would be able to criticize an argument based on its merits, but some apparently can't. Then again, I know people like that even in my department, so I'm not really terribly surprised. I can't help but wonder if "You are the goat!" is actually a compliment, though. Doesn't that stand for "the greatest of all time"?

Answer (score 27):

Take meteorites, for instance. By the end of the XVIII<sup>th</sup> century, educated people “knew” that no rock found on Earth could possibly have fallen from the sky, in spite of the evidence (eyewitnesses included) for their existence. As science journalist Kat Eshner [wrote](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/1803-rain-rocks-helped-establish-existence-meteorites-180963017/), “eighteenth-century rationalists […] thought the stories of rains of iron rocks weren’t real”. This state of affairs lasted until 1803, when Jean-Baptiste Biot [established the reality of meteorites](http://www.q-mag.org/whodunit-the-fall-of-a-meteorite-at-laigle-on-the-6th-of-floreal-of-the-year-11.html).

Comment: The WP link doesn't seem to support your interpretation. It sounds like the question was not even taken up by professional scientists until 1794, when Chladni, a professional scientist, published a book saying that they did fall from the sky. This was followed rapidly by the supporting evidence from Biot.

Comment: Your link doesn't support that people before that time "knew" that no rock could fall from the sky... In addition it certainly doesn't say that a non professional scientist did the research on the rock

Answer (score 23):

Just warning not to include pre-1920s medicine (and a lot of medical mantra thru the 20th century), as there was little to no science involved amongst physicians.  Just look at how difficult it was for Lister et. al. to convince hospitals, midwives, etc. to wash their hands and sterilize operating theatres.

There are dozens of incorrect anecdotes purporting to show scientists were wrong.  The "bumblebee can't fly" is one such.  The truth behind the science/engineering theories is rather different.

Comment: Note that the actual statement in the bumblebee case is "the bumblebee can't fly using aerodynamic lift" -- and in fact, it doesn't.  It flies using a different technique involving dynamic stall.

Comment: @Mark  I did know that;  it's one of those cliches that has ignored the true source. Just like the "Let them eat cake,"  where 'cake' had a completely different meaning (leftover scalings from bakeries, not fancy dessert items)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Although it's off topic, I don't know where you are getting that interpretation of "Let them eat cake". The origin of it that I know is that Jean-Jacques Rousseau attributed the phrase "Qu'ils mangent de la brioche." to a proverbial unspecified princess as part of a joke in his autobiography.

Comment: @Mark The bee thing always bothered me. The science wasn't *wrong*; no scientist ever claimed that bees can't fly or anything like that. The point was that using the science known at the time, they couldn't explain how bees were able to generate sufficient lift to fly, but, given that they clearly do fly, this hinted at principles of aerodynamics that were as yet not fully understood, thus pointing at new areas to research and new experiments to devise. It's not scientists being ignorant, it's scientists learning from observations. In other words, *doing science*.

Comment: Ironically, during the plague, the masks worn by doctors were stuffed with lavender (and other nice smelling flowers)... It had since been found this would have helped protect them from some diseases (though likely not the plague) because lavender is a natural anti biotic...

Answer (score 23):

The [Wright Brothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_brothers), both bicycle mechanics, solved both the control and power problems of [heavier-than-air manned flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_flying_machines#Powered,_controlled_flight) in 1902, beating the well funded aeronautical academic scientists of the Smithsonian Institute, notably [Samuel Pierpont Langley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Pierpont_Langley).

Comment: That is an example from engineering, not science. For that very fact, the people at the Smithsonian weren't wrong, since they weren't even trying to be right. Engineering problems can have multiple solutions.

Comment: The Wright Brothers do get full credit since they did their work independently; but weren't the first to achieve heavier-than-air manned flight. Richard Pearce's earlier (very similar) aircraft didn't have the same historical significance due mostly to its inventor's deteriorating mental state.

Comment: @JeremyList can you please provide a reference to Richard Pearce

Comment: @JishinNoben the Wrights demonstrated [scientific skills set](https://www.narst.org/publications/research/skill.cfm) associated with scientific inquiry.  As in 1) Literature review 2) contacting other flight researchers; 3) Thought up hypothesis' which were tested to develop a theory ( of flight eg wing warping); 4) Controlled variables (chord ratio of wings) 5) Built equipment to test the hypothesis (eg wind tunnel); Pulling together research to successful outcome (eg controlled manned flight in heavier air device). [NASA does the same process](https://wright.nasa.gov/overview.htm)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Pearse. Turns out there's a lot more uncertainty about his life and work than I had recalled, but this is still a very interesting read.

Comment: @russelld Engineering is an application of science, and surely does use scientific methods. But using scientific methods is not a sufficient ground for being called a scientist. One also has to consider *what* is investigated; engines are not a subject of science. Even if we let that drop, you still interpret "finding one of many solution" as "being right", which sounds very unreasonable.

Answer (score 22):

I'd be tempted to add [Gregor Mendel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregor_Mendel), whose experiments on plants and his analysis demonstrated how genes work, to that list.

It wasn't so much that the 'professional' scientists of the time considered that he was wrong — rather that they didn't even know of his results.  In particular, Darwin puzzled over what the mechanism for transfer of traits was and was searching for a reason why traits wouldn't be continually diluted — which was an answer that Mendel had already answered very neatly.  (Darwin argued for pangenesis as he was sure from his observations that blending inheritance would have diluted distinct traits.)

I'd argue that Mendel would meet the criteria as being a 'non-professional' as while he did teach physics — he repeatedly failed the teaching exams so he wasn't qualified to teach high school or adults - only young children.  A pedant may point out that as presented his experiments in a couple of meetings and published an ignored paper he should be regarded as a 'professional scientist', but since his own boss in the church banned him from studying mice as it was considered wrong to study animal reproduction — I'd safely argue that it was a very non-scientific profession he was in.

Comment: Actually, Mendel did once present his results to botanists. Most got bored of the lecture and left and none cared about what mathematics had to do with breeding plants.

Comment: @slebetman That sounds like a great anecdote. I would like to learn more about it. Do you have a reference?

Comment: Mendel's work wouldn't have helped Darwin: Mendel didn't explain *why* traits didn't get continually diluted, but rather, he developed a mathematical description of the lack of dilution.

Answer (score 21):

Michael Ventris, an amateur philologist, (he was an architect) managed to decipher the Mycenean script known as Linear B, a problem that professional specialists had been trying to solve for decades.

Comment: I guess "experts couldn't solve it" is not the same as "experts were wrong".

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Experts were wrong, since they didn't attempt to decipher those inscriptions assuming –as Ventris did– that they were written in a language related to Greek.

Comment: @xxavier Interesting. You should amend your answer with that detail, it makes it more relevant. It's also not untypical: Preconceived ideas sometimes prevent the professional from exploring new approaches.

Comment: @xxavier well no, there were attempt to decipher it via Greek but they moved on when they didn't have success.  The question is if they were confident enough on the matter to be considered wrong for this question.  It's tricky with ancient history as much of it is theories based on available evidence.  Also, Ventris wasn't a profession in the field but his collaborator, John Chadwich, definitely was.

Answer (score 19):

The [Green Flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_flash#Observing) was
described for the first time (at least in the Western literature) by Jules Verne,
a science fiction writer.
Many scientists did not believe until photographs were taken and published.

Herbert Wells in 1914 described the use of nuclear energy for both bombs and peaceful applications. (His novel The world Set Free). At approximately the same time many scientists thought this was impossible.
(Rutherford is on record for saying this publicly, that nuclear energy will be never used).

Comment: HG Wells wrote many science fiction novels. That one happened to reflect something which later turned out to be correct is really just the dice falling right, with a whole bunch of other novels which turned out not to work out. Anyway, Wells was always about the concept, and the society, not the hard science.

Comment: Can you provide a source that confirms the scientists did not believe the Green Flash was possible? The Wikipedia article mentions the photographs were published in 1960 and I clearly remember a 1920s children popular science book discussing green flash (after all, refraction has been studied for quite some time). Also, I find the idea that scientists changed their minds simply after looking at some photos dubious.

Answer (score 14):

Mathematicians have been looking for [amicable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amicable_numbers) for millenia. The smallest pair $(220, 284)$ was known to the Pythagoreans, and several larger pairs and a formula for generating them were found by Hindu and Arab mathematicians during the Middle Ages.  Fermat, Descartes, and Euler rediscovered some of these and found some more.

But in 1866, a 16-year old schoolboy, Nicolo I. Paganini (no relation to the composer) found the previously unknown pair $(1184, 1210)$, which is actually the second smallest.

Comment: In fact, Paganini was a distant relative of the composer (no link but ancestor of my mother). So there.

Comment: Are you saying implicitly that Hindu and Arab mathematicians were non-professionals? (This is what the question was about).

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Not. Even. Close. 16-year old Paganini was the non-professional here.

Answer (score 12):

The [Mpemba effect](https://medium.com/the-physics-arxiv-blog/why-hot-water-freezes-faster-than-cold-physicists-solve-the-mpemba-effect-d8a2f611e853),

> named after a Tanzanian student who discovered that a hot ice cream
>   mix freezes faster than a cold mix in cookery classes in the early
>   1960s

was initially ridiculed.  Quoting [the wiki page on this topic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpemba_effect):

> After [a lecture by Dr. Denis G. Osborne], Erasto Mpemba asked him the question, "If you take two similar containers with equal volumes of water, one at 35 °C (95 °F) and the other at 100 °C (212 °F), and put them into a freezer, the one that started at 100 °C (212 °F) freezes first. Why?", only to be ridiculed by his classmates and teacher. After initial consternation, Osborne experimented on the issue back at his workplace and confirmed Mpemba's finding. They published the results together in 1969.

Comment: Do you have another source for this, because the article you link to does not agree with your statement you make. Apparently this was a well known but unexplained observation that a lot of very famous physicists had observed.

Comment: @pipe I basically quote from the article but the wiki page is also good: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpemba_effect

Comment: Wasn't the Mpemba effect debunked? Wasn't evaporation the key?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo. you get *less* ice due to evaporation but the effect is real, i.e. the hot water does freeze faster.

Answer (score 11):

Rogue/Freak waves. It seems that reports of these were considered myths by science for a long time until they were finally recorded.

(However this is not an exact answer to the question - no non-professional had a theory about these waves, it was more of "ignoring observed facts which don't fit the accepted theory)

Answer (score 4):

The [abacists](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abacist) of 16th century Italy correctly identified the rule of signs from multiplication.  Typical of their arguments (using modern notation) is:

> $64 = (10 - 2) \times (10 - 2) = \dots =100 + (-40) + (-2\times-2) = 60 + (-2\times-2),$

so that "subtract 2 times subtract 2" must equal four. (There was still no concept of a negative number.)

[Cardano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerolamo_Cardano) insisted that the abacists were mistaken, giving a geometric argument that the arithmetic situation here was (using modern algebraic notation):

> $64 = (10 - 2) \times (10 - 2) =(10\times10) - (2\times20) + (2\times2),$

where the "$-(2\times20)$" corresponds to removing two rectangles from the larger square and the "$+ (2\times2)"$ adds back the smallest square that has now been removed twice.

Answer (score 3):

Amateur makes fools of the experts, Marcus Chown September 1995,
[https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg14719952-200-amateur-makes-fools-of-the-experts/] 
.

> An experiment  that for eighty years has been cited by physicists as a
>   confirmation of Einstein’s special theory of relativity is nothing of
>   the sort. This remarkable discovery has been made not by a
>   professional physicist but by an enthusiastic amateur.
>
> Prominent physicists are often pestered by people who claim to have
>   found a flaw in our understanding of the Universe. So Arthur Swift of
>   the University of Massachusetts in Amherst at first ignored the
>   letters he received from Gerald Pellegrini of Worcester,
>   Massachusetts. “He has spent twenty years in the wilderness mulling
>   over fundamental problems,” says Swift.
>
> However, Pellegrini’s insistence that there was something amiss with a
>   classic 1913 experiment eventually persuaded Swift to take a closer
>   look at the theory behind the original experiment. This experiment,
>   reported in the Proceedings of the Royal Society A, was an attempt by
>   the husband-and-wife team Marjorie Wilson and H. A. Wilson of Rice
>   University in Houston to measure the electric field created in a
>   magnetised nonconducting material moving at high speed through a
>   uniform magnetic field. Five years earlier, Einstein had used his
>   special theory of relativity to predict that such an electric field
>   would be stronger than that predicted using the classical theory
>   devised by the Dutch physicist Hendrik Lorentz.

.

Amateur Scientists Just Proved Einstein Wrong Alfredo Carpineti May 2018
https://www.iflscience.com/physics/one-of-einsteins-major-theories-just-got-disproved-by-a-bunch-of-amateurs/

.

> Proving Albert Einstein wrong is something that only a small number of
>   scientists can claim to have done but now, more than 100,000 gamers
>   can join that exclusive club and enjoy the smugness that comes with
>   it. In 2016, scientists from around the world led by the Institute of
>   Photonic Sciences in Barcelona (ICFO) asked people to play a simple
>   game online, and the results were used to disprove one of Einstein’s
>   claims about quantum mechanics. The results are published in Nature.
>
> One of the things Einstein truly disliked about quantum mechanics is
>   how the experimenter plays a role in the results obtained from an
>   experiment. He believed the universe to be independent of our actions
>   and quantum mechanics to be governed by the principle of local
>   realism.

.

*It Doesn't Take a Rocket Scientist: Great Amateurs of Science* John Malone
https://archive.org/details/ItDoesntTakeARocketScientist-GreatAmateursInScience/mode/2up
.

> *It Doesn't Take a Rocket Scientist* examines the lives and work of ten amateur scientists whose investigations yielded insights and
>   discoveries that eluded their highly educated counterparts.

.
.

Amateur Scientists Making Significant Discoveries While Fighting To Receive Recognition And Respect Bruce Bigelow Jun 10, 1996
https://www.the-scientist.com/news/amateur-scientists-making-significant-discoveries-while-fighting-to-receive-recognition-and-respect-57972 
.

> Discoveries While Fighting To Receive Recognition And Respect In
>   Tucson, Ariz., David Levy is a freelance writer and educator who
>   spends his nights watching the desert sky for comets. STRUGGLE:
>   Forrest Mims III, shown during a trip to the Mauna Loa Observatory,
>   has encountered resistance to his efforts to work at the site. In
>   Miami, Randy McCranie is a postal worker who has conducted extensive
>   investigations as a field biologist in Honduras. And in Seguin, Texas,
>   Forrest M. Mims III is a pro.

.
.

The British amateur who debunked the mathematics of happiness Andrew Anthony Jan. 2014
https://www.theguardian.com/science/2014/jan/19/mathematics-of-happiness-debunked-nick-brown
.
.

> The astonishing story of Nick Brown, the British man who began a
>   part-time psychology course in his 50s – and ended up taking on
>   America's academic establishment

Answer (score 3):

Einstein of course.

He had been working in a patent office for three years when he formulated the theory of relativity, gave an explanation of the photo-electric effect and an explanation of Brownian motion.

One shouldn't discount the fact he had been trained as a physicist, nevertheless, he was a non-professional physicist at the time he published his papers.

Comment: Mmm... I wouldn't qualify Einstein as "non-professional scientist", even when he was working at the Swiss Patent Office. But maybe the problem is what does the OP mean by "non-professional"?

Comment: @Charo: Is this the same way you wouldn't classify a doctorate as a habilitation?

Comment: Well, I quote, for instance, John S. Ridgen in his book *Einstein 1905. The Standard of Greatness*: "His professional career began December 13, 1900, when he finished his first scholarly paper. His career ended on the day he died, Monday, April 18, 1955, at 1:15 in the morning".

Comment: @Charo: Nevertheless he wasn't employed as a professional scientist at the time he wrote his first paper; I think John Ridgen would confirm that fact.

Answer (score 2):

Poet Edgar Allan Poe is considered to be the first to solve [Olber's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olbers%27s_paradox) in *Eureka: A prose poem* of 1848. Lord Kelvin came with the same argument 50-ish years later, however the solution would not be agreed upon until experimental verification in the 1920-1930s of a non-static universe.

Comment: Poe's text "Eureka" is not a poem. It's a bit hard to say what genre it belongs to, but it's definitely not a poem.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg it's literally subtitled "A prose poem" maybe I will use that

Answer (score 1):

Several species of animals  [were long regarded by scientists as cryptids](http://web.archive.org/web/20210218012215/https://blogs.iu.edu/sciu/2020/12/12/seven-cryptids-species/) but are now known to be real, e.g., the platypus, okapi, and giant squid.